# Can I use PayPal to change product prices based on location?

Tags: paypal, currency, paypal-adaptive-payments

Can I use PayPal as currency conversion.

I run a global site, and am introducing multiple currency - USD, GBP, EUR, AUD, YEN.

When a user selects their selected currency I need the prices to reflect the conversion across our web and mobile platform

Answer (score 1):

You can use PayPal to charge buyers in all these currencies, but unfortunately you cannot use PayPal for all your currency conversion and display the prices on your site.
However, if you're selling in GBP and your buyer's funding sources are in EUR, we will of course automatically convert these.

Note; our Adaptive Payments product does offer a 'CurrencyConversion' API call, but this API call is not intended for on-the-fly calculation for your product listings.

Comment: so if buyer selects currency "EUR" and the seller has posted item in "GBP" what is the best/most accurate way for buy to see converted "EUR" price?

Comment: Can you confirm what PayPal product you're intending to integrate with; Payments Standard, Payments Pro, Express Checkout, Adaptive Payments or REST API's?

Comment: Currently using adaptive payments for our current functions just trying to find the best conversion solution